# Xtext rule has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations

Tags: syntax, grammar, xtext

I am trying to implement a simple grammar in Xtext to **recognise a function call** composed of IDs and function calls divided by a dot (Java-like syntax). I.e. whatever chain composed of IDs and/or functions, always ending by a function.

Example source code: `a.b(a).c(b()).b.d();`

I have written the following Xtext grammar:

```
Test: Chain ';';
Chain: (IdOrFunc '.')* ID Func;
IdOrFunc: ID Func?;
Func: '(' IdOrFunc? ')';
```

However, I get the following error when trying to generate the language code by Xtext:

```
[fatal] rule ruleChain has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.
```

The grammar starts to work if I replace `ID` in the `Chain` rule by `'xyz'`, i.e.

```
Chain: (IdOrFunc '.')* 'xyz' Func;`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

And what about :

```
Test: Chain ';';
Chain: IdOrFunc ('.' ID Func)*;
IdOrFunc: ID Func?;
Func: '(' IdOrFunc? ')';
```

I'm not completely sure it parses the exact same expressions, however, as I just had a quick look at it (the left recursion was in the (IdOrFund '.')* statement).

Comment: Your grammar does a different thing - it detects for example:
a(); a; a().b; The intention was that the qualified name ends by a function, i.e. a.b().c.d().